# 2015 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2015 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://photo.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 1):

I see that we're electing one moderator. I'd like to suggest that we add *two* new ones, and that perhaps some of the existing moderators who have become busy with other things (no shame in that!) can hang up their hats to make room.

(Vote this up if you agree, and down if you don't.)

Comment: It was discussed with respect to need and we didn't think the load required 2 additional moderators at the moment. The biggest factor is that a very large part of the moderation is coming from the users in general, so there's not a lot of real moderation demand on a daily basis (2-3 flags or less usually).